# How to select second column of every xts in list

Tags: r

I have a list containing 100 xts files of same dimensions. Now I want to select second column of every file.

I have used following code but this selects second row of every file

```
lapply(list,"[",c(2))
```

Please suggest how to modify above code to select columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the second column below is one (of many) solution(s).

```
lapply(list, function(x) x[, 2])
```

Or if the xts objects are OLHC then use quantmod's `Hi` function

```
lapply(list, quantmod::Hi)
```

For the rest, just search SO for "select column", there are loads of different solutions.